# Update existing json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have an input json as:

```
{   
   "setInfo":{  
      "userset1":{  
         "details1":[  
            "somedata1",
            "somedata2"
         ],
         "details2":[  
            "somedata3",
            "somedata4"
         ]
      },
      "userset2":{  
         "details3":[  
            "somedata5",
            "somedata6"
         ],
         "details4":[  
            "somedata7",
            "somedata8"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I want to convert this into below output json:

```
{  
   "setInfo":{  
      "userset1":{  
         "details1":{  
            "options":[  
               "op1",
               "op2",
               "op3"
            ]
         },
         "details2":{  
            "options":[  
               "op1",
               "op3"
            ]
         }
      },
      "userset2":{  
         "details3":{  
            "options":[  
               "op1"
            ]
         },
         "details4":{  
            "options":[  
               "op4"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In the above input json somedata1, somedata2...somedata8 are variables that I need to pass to a service endpoint that would return me corresponding options for details1.....details4 which are op1,op2 etc
So I want to loop through the above input json and update the above with values returned from my service.

So I tried with the below code.

```
//my inital service call to get data
myservice.getData().then(function(result){

// Below is console output from result.setInfo
//  setInfo:
//      userset1:
//        details1: (2) ["somedata1", "somedata2"]
//        details2: (2) ["somedata3", "somedata4"].
//      userset2:
//        details3: (2) ["somedata5", "somedata6"]
//        details4: (2) ["somedata7", "somedata8"]


//Now I tried looping through the json and update but not getting through as I feel something is incorrect below
_.each(result.setInfo, function (set, name) {

  $scope.sets[name] = {};  
    _.each(set, function (data1, name1) {

       //This is the service which gets corresponding options op1,op2 etc according to the params that were passed
       myservice.getArrayData({ data: data1}).function((res){

          //this is where I feel something is not correct. .pluck gets the correponding data fine but its the assignment which is not correct.
          $scope.sets[name].setInfo[name].options = _.pluck(res, 'name');

       });
    });
   });
});
```

With the above code I get the below json which is not what I expect,

```
 {  
     "setInfo":{  
           "userset1":{  
              "options":[  
                 "op1",
                 "op2"
              ]
           },
           "userset2":{  
              "options":[  
                 "op1",
                 "op2"
              ]
           }
       }
    }
```

So see how it removed some tags above.

Could anyone point me to whats missing.
Sorry for long post but wanted to cover as much as I can.

--Updated--

So I updated to use this code

```
 $scope.setInfo[name][name1] = _.pluck(jobs, 'name');
```

And with this I made further progress that now my output json became as:

```
 {  
   "setInfo":{  
      "userset1":{  
         "details1":[  
            "op1",
            "op2",
            "op3"
         ],
         "details2":[  
            "op1",
            "op3"
         ]
      },
      "userset2":{  
         "details3":[  
            "op1"
         ],
         "details4":[  
            "op4"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

So the only thing missing here is how to add the options tag.

I tried with this

```
 $scope.setInfo[name][name1].options = _.pluck(jobs, 'name');
```

But this gives me error:

```
Cannot set property 'options' of undefined
```

Comment: Both data are the same.

Comment: my apologies. I have updated my post.

Comment: You're almost there. Replace `$scope.setInfo[name][name1].options = _.pluck(jobs, 'name');` with `$scope.setInfo[name][name1] = {options: _.pluck(jobs, 'name');}`

Comment: Thank you, that resolved it.